# UIWebview disable redirect to AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have `UIWebview` in my app and this is how i navigate some times in the application to `URL`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mp3skull.com/mp3/nirvana.html"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:request];
```

And sometimes i noticed that if i click on link the `AppStore` application is opened with some app.

It is possible to disable it?

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

You could do

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *requestedURL = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    // URL for opening itunes according to Apple docs is something like this @"http://itunes.apple.com
    // But I do believe that it will be some sort of URL scheme that opens it specifically to the app on the app store.
    // So without an example this is the best I can provide.
    if([requestedURL isEqualToString:@"http://itunes.apple.com"]) {
    // or   if([requestedURL rangeOfString:@"itunes.apple.com"].location==0) {
        // What is happening here is that if the request url that is being request is 
        // "http://mp3skull.com/mp3/nirvana.html" then we don't want to continue with the request so stop.
        return NO;
    }
    // Otherwise for all other requests continue
    return YES;
}
```

Remember you will need to set the delegate on your `UIWebView` as this method is a `UIWebViewDelegate` method - see [Apple Documentation on `UIWebViewDelegate` for more information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951-CH3-SW6)

Comment: Thanks, but i wrote that if i click on a link in this page it's happen,or any other page

Comment: @MTA What is the URL behind these links??? As you haven't provided them I just used the one that you did supply. By the sounds of it, it will be a url scheme set up which using this same method you can block but unless you supply the an example link I am guessing at the link. Please supply.

Comment: `http://mp3skull.com/mp3/nirvana.html` it's a goog link but inside it there are links that open the app store application. i want to block that app store links

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of these links just so we can see if it is any different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it happens, some times when you click on some links, the application will open another application.

Because, those links contain other app schemas. ([link](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes))
so, to disable opening such url-schemas, we have to detect them and not load them.

As appStore has "itunes.apple.com",

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *requestedURL = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    if([requestedURL  rangeOfString:@"itunes.apple.com"].location==0) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```