# How to Turn off redirection when shared link is already in my Dropbox?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, dropbox

When i load the dropbox shared link in UIwebview in IOS, If the link exists in my Dropbox app, it redirects me out of the current app to dropbox. Is there any webview property to stop redirection?

I currently load the link using the below code:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.webLink]]];
```

Comment: The technique described in these posts may work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144616/how-to-detect-redirect-in-a-uiwebview 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909886/uiwebview-disable-redirect-to-appstore